# Do all Windows processes have an associated command-line, or is it only processes that are launched from the shell?

Tags: windows

Consider the below questions that asks for displaying the command-line (and arguments) for running processes:

https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program

https://serverfault.com/questions/323795/display-complete-command-line-including-arguments-for-windows-process

Now, do all Windows processes have an associated command-line, or is it only those that have been launched from the shell (e.g. `cmd.exe`)?

In the picture below, we see that some processes have an empty command-line?

[image]

Comment: If you are not running with elevation, your account has no permission to grovel around in the process memory to get the command line for processes running under credentials other than yours. Run Task Manager as an administrator and try again. (And yes, all Windows processes have a command line, which they can obtain with `GetCommandLine()`; what it actually contains is a function of what gets passed to `CreateProcess()` plus some logic the OS itself adds.)

Answer (score 1):

Processes are created on Windows using `CreateProcess`, see [the Windows doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), whether by `cmd.exe` or any other method. One of the args to that function is `lpCommandLine`, the command line to be used. So yes, every Windows process *has* a command line. If that is NULL, the application name is used instead. It can be blank (zero-length string), however, if you want to hide what the process is doing.

(There is also a very-low-level `NtCreateProcess` syscall, see the docs if you're interested.)

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. However, I guess the `lpCommandLine` argument name is a bit misleading, since there is no "command-line" involved, rather a Window API call? I also find it wierd that `lpApplicationName` specify the module name, when `lpCommandLine` does so too? In that case both `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` will contain the module name, right?

Comment: In NT 6+, the system call used by `CreateProcess[AsUser]W` is `NtCreateUserProcess`, which implements new features and some of the setup that used to be implemented in user mode, but the PEB's `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` record is still set up in user mode. This includes parameters such as `CommandLine` and `ImagePath`, which can come from either `lpCommandLine` or `lpApplicationName`. Processes created by `NtCreateProcess[Ex]` (or `PsCreateSystemProcess` within the kernel) don't necessarily have a command line. The most common example is the system process, PID 4.

Comment: @Shuzheng, if a `CreateProcess[AsUser]W` call doesn't provide `lpCommandLine`, then it must provide `lpApplicationName`, in which case the executable path is used as the command line. (If the created process uses the C/C++ runtime `argv` parsing, which isn't necessarily the case, then this will be `argv[0]`, and there won't be an `argv[1]`.) If the call doesn't provide `lpApplicationName`, then it must provide `lpCommandLine`, in which case it slices out the command from the command line based on white space and double-quoting rules, and searches for the executable via `SearchPathW`.

Comment: @Shuzheng, if a `CreateProcess[AsUser]W` call uses both `lpCommandLine` and `lpApplicationName`, then it can create a process in which the command line has nothing to do with the executable path. In this case, if the created process uses C/C++ `argv` parsing (or similarly WINAPI `CommandLineToArgvW`), then `argv[0]` is unrelated to the process executable image.

Comment: @eryksun - don't "Because argv[0] is the module name, C programmers generally repeat the module name as the first token in the command line." from the `CreateProcess` reference means that both `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` will contain the module name, if it's both specified in `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine`? Or does it mean that `argv[0]` (first token in `lpCommandLine`) should always be equal to `lpApplicationName` (if specified) by convention?

Comment: @Shuzheng, if `lpCommandLine` is specified, then `lpApplicationName` has nothing in principle to do with the process command line. By convention for C/C++ `argv` handling, we expect that if `lpApplicationName` name is used, it's related to the first token of the command line and preferably what ends up at `argv[0]` should run the same program based on the inherited working directory. For example, the command line may be "cmd /c dir", and `lpApplicationName` may be "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe". This is all just convention. Windows programs don't even have to use a C style `main` entry point.